# react-saga call function on source component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm pretty unsure how to ask this correctly. (I'm sorry) Basically I want to call the **onError** function in my Component with the Error String when the Saga function got a error. So I can fire up the Snackbar for 5 sec and then hide it again.

But I don't know how exactly I can call this Function from my Saga function. Currently it return the error on the `this.state.error` State as String. I tried to use `componentWillReceiveProps` but this doesn't work on the 2nd try when the string is still the same.

To avoid a xyproblem I'll just post the piece of code that I have.

I got the following component:

```
class RegisterForm extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      username: '',
      password: '',
      SnackbarOpen: false,
    };
  }
  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.register(this.state.email, this.state.username, this.state.password);
  }

  onError(error) {
    this.setState({SnackbarOpen: true})
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({SnackbarOpen: false});
    }, 5000);
  }

  render(): with <form>
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  error: state.auth.error,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  register: (email, username, password) => {
    dispatch(Actions.register(email, username, password));
  }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RegisterForm);
```

Which call this Redux-Saga Function:

```
import { Types } from './Actions';
import CognitoService from './CognitoService';

function* register(action) {
  try {
    const result = yield call(CognitoService.register, action);
    yield put({ type: Types.registrationSuccess, user: result.user });
  } catch(error) {
    yield put({ type: Types.registrationFail, error: error.message });
  }
}

function* authSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(Types.register, register);
}

export default authSaga;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a switch case to your `auth` reducer to match on the action type: **Types.registrationFail**. It should then pull out the registered error message and assign it to the `auth.error` field in your auth state. e.g.

```
authReducer(prevState, action){
    ...
    switch(action.type){
        case Types.registrationFail: 
            return {
                ...prevState,
                error: action.error
            };
    }
    ...
}
```

Your component will pick up the store change via the `connect(..)` function. Then simply update your component with the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method to check the value of this message. e.g.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState){
    if(nextProps.error != null && ! nextState.SnackbarOpen){
        this.onError();
    }
}
```

Making the assumption here that your snackbar is in within this component as well and simply pull its display text from the `this.props.error` value. Otherwise, there is scope to clean this up a bit more.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have now a better way on handling those errors by using redux-form. Thanks anyway for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In this situation I see two solutions. The first one is more preferable, I think, with redux saga usual approach.

**Rendering based on the store values**

In your example you save "SnackbarOpen" variable on state level.

```
this.setState({SnackbarOpen: true})
```

Instead you can have a peace of store for the "register" component and save that variable there. So in such case, saga will change that value in the store on error. Simple example is:

```
 function* register(action) {
  try {
    const result = yield call(CognitoService.register, action);
    yield put({ type: Types.registrationSuccess, user: result.user });
  } catch(error) {
    yield put({ type: Types.registrationFail, error: error.message });
    yield put({ type: Types.registrationSnackBarOpen });
    yield delay(5000);
    yield put({ type: Types.registrationSnackBarClose });
  }
}
```

And, of course, bind that value to your component.

**Adding callbacks**

I don't recommend to use such approach, but it still exists. You can just add callbacks to your actions and call them in sagas. For example:

Component:

```
this.props.register(this.state.email, this.state.username, this.state.password, this.onError.bind(this);
```

Saga:

```
 function* register(action) {
  try {
    const result = yield call(CognitoService.register, action);
    yield put({ type: Types.registrationSuccess, user: result.user });
  } catch(error) {
    yield put({ type: Types.registrationFail, error: error.message });
    action.onError();
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have now a better way on handling those errors by using redux-form. Thanks anyway for your help!